# Deleting old rows in a schema using stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, psql

Is there a way to select all tables in a schema and delete rows that do not fit the condition (older than some date) in one procedure? I can do the same thing using 2 separate queries,
It would look something like: `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables  WHERE table_schema = 'schemaName'` and then `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE time < now()-'12 months'::interval;"` but cannot put my head on how to do the same using one stored procedure, I assume I should use for loop on some type of select query, but since I never realy worked with loops in postgres I always get some type of exception trying to do this.
Any help appreciated a lot

Comment: You should be able to embed your sql statements in a procedure without using a loop. Do you have an exact description of your SELECT statement and which works ?

Comment: the queries in the question are the ones i used (only have changed table/shema names), an aproach I used is running first query, then getting the names of the tables using some java code and then using second query for every table name on the list. Cant realy get how to combine them in one procedure

Answer (score 0):

You can typically combine both SELECT and DELETE statements using a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) :

```
WITH list AS
( SELECT ...
    FROM ...
   WHERE ...
RETURNING ...
)
DELETE FROM ...
USING list
WHERE ...
```

Except the fact that in your case, the returned parameter of the SELECT statement corresponds to the name of the table where rows must be deleted. This means that the table name is not known before the run time, and this implies to use a [dynamic sql command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) within a plpgsql `FUNCTION` :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_rows_from_table(table_name text)
RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
EXECUTE E'
DELETE FROM ' || quote_ident(table_name) || E'
 WHERE time < now()- \'12 months\':: interval' ;
END ;
$$ ;
```

Then you can use the `FUNCTION` delete_rows_from_table in your `SELECT` statement :

```
SELECT delete_rows_from_table(table_name)
  FROM information_schema.tables
 WHERE table_schema = 'schemaName'
```